# Get file path from request

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, socket.io

I have the following files:
app.js

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(8000);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
if (err) {
  res.writeHead(500);
  return res.end('Error loading index.html');
}

res.writeHead(200);
res.end(data);
  });
}
```

index.html (only the 'head' is shown here):

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="Client">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
<meta name="viewport"
      content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slider.css"/>
<title>Web Client: Robot control</title>
</head>
```

I first execute my nodejs server: node app.js
When I run

```
http://localhost:8000/index.html
```

even when the request is for a different file, example: css/app.css, the server (app.js)
returns the index.html file. So my output is very wrong.

May I know how I can parse the request in app.js, to get the url field, and then extract the required file name from it?

Thank you.

**SOLVED**
By doing the following -

```
  var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
  fs.readFile(__dirname + pathname,
```

You will need the following line as well:

```
var url = require('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
req.url
```

this variable is what you need, if you request 127.0.0.1:8000/index.html, the req.url is /index.html; if you request 127.0.0.1:8000/css/filename, the req.url is /css/filename

Comment: I tried printing req.print as such:
    function handler (req, res) {
      console.log(req.path);
      ...

but it keeps printing 'undefined'.

Comment: @Jayson sorry for my careless answer, you should try req.url for that.